# How can I improve this nesting logic to make it work properly and be performant

Tags: go, nested

I have a database with comments, each has an ID and a parent ID. The goal is simply to put each comment with a parent ID under its parent comment in a performant way.

I was originally using a recursive function to search the `arranged` array for parent comments, but the performance was abysmal. I refactored to use pointers to keep track of parents instead, and that works almost perfectly, but it seems that the last comment to be processed is always excluded from the output.

In the example below, "comment 1" should be a child of "comment 11", but it is not included in the output at all.

```golang
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

// Comment from Database
type Comment struct {
  ID       string `json:"id""`
  ParentID string `json:"pid"`
  Text     string `json:"text"`
}

// NestedComment output
type NestedComment struct {
  Comment
  Children []NestedComment `json:"children,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
  // Some comment data from DB
  jsondata := `[{"id":"f1c3a838-f4b4-4ebd-bb1b-d3e4c0dce27d","pid":"6a162b3f-9341-46e9-95f7-dedc6cd06868","text":"comment 1"},{"id":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","pid":"","text":"comment 2"},{"id":"4c93a789-ecab-4173-954c-b039cd3a9e17","pid":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","text":"comment 3"},{"id":"c7974b6d-67e1-47d0-84fa-c78d51682df2","pid":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","text":"comment 4"},{"id":"386c4439-4596-47c1-99bf-cb479055fe5a","pid":"","text":"comment 5"},{"id":"5ef0816e-ea13-4a7e-8009-e67ee08ef906","pid":"386c4439-4596-47c1-99bf-cb479055fe5a","text":"comment 6"},{"id":"96b0a536-602b-4f3f-a352-020f22cdfb18","pid":"","text":"comment 7"},{"id":"d0f11e98-deea-4fd5-becb-8f406ebcae83","pid":"96b0a536-602b-4f3f-a352-020f22cdfb18","text":"comment 8"},{"id":"bad87461-3cbf-4ecb-a8c7-36876b57d652","pid":"","text":"comment 9"},{"id":"e3ee6f90-495f-4348-9c29-bd6e15ec3b39","pid":"bad87461-3cbf-4ecb-a8c7-36876b57d652","text":"comment 10"},{"id":"6a162b3f-9341-46e9-95f7-dedc6cd06868","pid":"","text":"comment 11"},{"id":"041c7c2d-0688-491e-b6cd-899eac95bd3d","pid":"","text":"comment 12"},{"id":"5acdf3ff-345b-47a5-bd66-a6687a1441b7","pid":"041c7c2d-0688-491e-b6cd-899eac95bd3d","text":"comment 13"},{"id":"aaee2ae5-7e3a-4435-a094-83bf6b77abfb","pid":"","text":"comment 14"},{"id":"6108b28c-a7af-4c5a-a38c-c22db0d34b31","pid":"aaee2ae5-7e3a-4435-a094-83bf6b77abfb","text":"comment 15"},{"id":"1736393e-95b0-4f5d-a149-50fe52c28350","pid":"","text":"comment 16"},{"id":"b646f202-17aa-4af9-b8dc-c1d8ff3529ac","pid":"1736393e-95b0-4f5d-a149-50fe52c28350","text":"comment 17"},{"id":"a8827b1d-fdbc-41c2-bdb5-38e8b308dedc","pid":"b646f202-17aa-4af9-b8dc-c1d8ff3529ac","text":"comment 18"},{"id":"76e49597-6039-4cb5-a595-556ccc2e3c12","pid":"a8827b1d-fdbc-41c2-bdb5-38e8b308dedc","text":"comment 19"},{"id":"07dc4b90-65d3-4f75-8351-457305988235","pid":"76e49597-6039-4cb5-a595-556ccc2e3c12","text":"comment 20"},{"id":"2d4e838b-82df-4ca0-bf9b-f1dfb99d6763","pid":"07dc4b90-65d3-4f75-8351-457305988235","text":"comment 21"},{"id":"617c1760-0dca-409c-af2a-c614f0530e07","pid":"","text":"comment 22"},{"id":"712c0b7e-a9e4-40fd-ab78-c39b483b1435","pid":"617c1760-0dca-409c-af2a-c614f0530e07","text":"comment 23"},{"id":"e325094c-886e-42c9-bd59-fdd7a189b384","pid":"","text":"comment 24"},{"id":"f3b8b0f9-edef-4ee6-9555-42e8595f854c","pid":"e325094c-886e-42c9-bd59-fdd7a189b384","text":"comment 25"},{"id":"6e09a231-a2ee-4aa1-a898-57695e6fe153","pid":"","text":"comment 26"},{"id":"63e629d6-c0f9-4b36-ad96-e0c47cf8bb4e","pid":"6e09a231-a2ee-4aa1-a898-57695e6fe153","text":"comment 27"},{"id":"d7b698f1-8757-46db-a6e6-5141a481b42b","pid":"","text":"comment 28"},{"id":"a7e3d522-553c-44f1-befa-047bd94f0e59","pid":"","text":"comment 29"},{"id":"fe78ce24-c2c8-4d00-b96d-8b8be9ce0f06","pid":"","text":"comment 30"},{"id":"fabdccb5-a024-4476-bd51-7d55fb685c42","pid":"","text":"comment 31"},{"id":"608d0693-6e43-46a0-9e54-107da6adb109","pid":"fabdccb5-a024-4476-bd51-7d55fb685c42","text":"comment 32"}]`

  var comments []Comment

  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsondata), &comments)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  arranged := ArrangeComments(comments, len(comments))

  arrangedjson, _ := json.MarshalIndent(arranged, "", "  ")

  fmt.Println(string(arrangedjson))
  fmt.Println("comments", len(comments), "arranged", recursiveCount(arranged))
}

func recursiveCount(arranged []NestedComment) int {
    count := len(arranged)
    for _, item := range arranged {
        count += recursiveCount(item.Children)
    }
    return count
}

// Nesting function -------------------------------------------------------------------------

func ArrangeComments(queue []Comment, count int) []NestedComment {
  var arranged []NestedComment

  // using pointers over a recursive search
  var refs []*NestedComment

  // some comments are orphaned, se we need a bail out
  tries := 0
  maxTries := 5
  prevPlacedLen := 0

  // IDs of placed comments
  var placed []string

  // while count is greater then length of placed
countloop:
  for count > len(placed) {
    // loop through queue
  queueloop:
    for _, item := range queue {

      // skip if already placed
      if len(placed) > 0 {
        for _, id := range placed {
          if id == item.ID {
            continue queueloop
          }
        }
      }

      // if parent is nil, add to arranged
      if item.ParentID == "" {
        arranged = append(arranged, NestedComment{
          Comment: item,
        })
        refs = append(refs, &arranged[len(arranged)-1])
        placed = append(placed, item.ID)
      } else {
        // if parent is not nil, loop through refs and add to children
      refloop:
        for _, ref := range refs {
          if ref.ID == item.ParentID {
            ref.Children = append(ref.Children, NestedComment{Comment: item})
            refs = append(refs, &ref.Children[len(ref.Children)-1])
            placed = append(placed, item.ID)
            break refloop
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // if no comments were placed, bail out after x tries
    if len(placed) == prevPlacedLen {
      if tries >= maxTries {
        break countloop
      }
      tries++
      break
    }

    prevPlacedLen = len(placed)
  }

  return arranged
}
```

---

Update; this got me closer, but will fail to nest some of the deeper nested comments. It also, strangely, produces different output each time it is run:

```golang
func ArrangeComments(comments []Comment) []NestedComment {
    // Map to hold references to NestedComment by their ID
    queue := make(map[string]*NestedComment)

    // Result slice
    var result []NestedComment

    // First, create all NestedComments and store references in the map
    for _, comment := range comments {
        nc := &NestedComment{Comment: comment}
        queue[comment.ID] = nc
    }

    // Second, loop through the map and add children to their parents
    for _, comment := range queue {
        if comment.ParentID != "" {
            parent := queue[comment.Comment.ParentID]
            if parent != nil {
                parent.Children = append(parent.Children, *comment)
            }
        }
    }

    // Third, loop through the map and add all root comments to the result slice
    for _, comment := range queue {
        if comment.ParentID == "" {
            result = append(result, *comment)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

---

Update; I whipped up a quick JavaScript implementation that produces the correct results given the same example data, and I can't figure out why this JS code works and the Go code does not work.

```js
const datajson = `[{"id":"f1c3a838-f4b4-4ebd-bb1b-d3e4c0dce27d","pid":"6a162b3f-9341-46e9-95f7-dedc6cd06868","text":"comment 1"},{"id":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","pid":"","text":"comment 2"},{"id":"4c93a789-ecab-4173-954c-b039cd3a9e17","pid":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","text":"comment 3"},{"id":"c7974b6d-67e1-47d0-84fa-c78d51682df2","pid":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","text":"comment 4"},{"id":"386c4439-4596-47c1-99bf-cb479055fe5a","pid":"","text":"comment 5"},{"id":"5ef0816e-ea13-4a7e-8009-e67ee08ef906","pid":"386c4439-4596-47c1-99bf-cb479055fe5a","text":"comment 6"},{"id":"96b0a536-602b-4f3f-a352-020f22cdfb18","pid":"","text":"comment 7"},{"id":"d0f11e98-deea-4fd5-becb-8f406ebcae83","pid":"96b0a536-602b-4f3f-a352-020f22cdfb18","text":"comment 8"},{"id":"bad87461-3cbf-4ecb-a8c7-36876b57d652","pid":"","text":"comment 9"},{"id":"e3ee6f90-495f-4348-9c29-bd6e15ec3b39","pid":"bad87461-3cbf-4ecb-a8c7-36876b57d652","text":"comment 10"},{"id":"6a162b3f-9341-46e9-95f7-dedc6cd06868","pid":"","text":"comment 11"},{"id":"041c7c2d-0688-491e-b6cd-899eac95bd3d","pid":"","text":"comment 12"},{"id":"5acdf3ff-345b-47a5-bd66-a6687a1441b7","pid":"041c7c2d-0688-491e-b6cd-899eac95bd3d","text":"comment 13"},{"id":"aaee2ae5-7e3a-4435-a094-83bf6b77abfb","pid":"","text":"comment 14"},{"id":"6108b28c-a7af-4c5a-a38c-c22db0d34b31","pid":"aaee2ae5-7e3a-4435-a094-83bf6b77abfb","text":"comment 15"},{"id":"1736393e-95b0-4f5d-a149-50fe52c28350","pid":"","text":"comment 16"},{"id":"b646f202-17aa-4af9-b8dc-c1d8ff3529ac","pid":"1736393e-95b0-4f5d-a149-50fe52c28350","text":"comment 17"},{"id":"a8827b1d-fdbc-41c2-bdb5-38e8b308dedc","pid":"b646f202-17aa-4af9-b8dc-c1d8ff3529ac","text":"comment 18"},{"id":"76e49597-6039-4cb5-a595-556ccc2e3c12","pid":"a8827b1d-fdbc-41c2-bdb5-38e8b308dedc","text":"comment 19"},{"id":"07dc4b90-65d3-4f75-8351-457305988235","pid":"76e49597-6039-4cb5-a595-556ccc2e3c12","text":"comment 20"},{"id":"2d4e838b-82df-4ca0-bf9b-f1dfb99d6763","pid":"07dc4b90-65d3-4f75-8351-457305988235","text":"comment 21"},{"id":"617c1760-0dca-409c-af2a-c614f0530e07","pid":"","text":"comment 22"},{"id":"712c0b7e-a9e4-40fd-ab78-c39b483b1435","pid":"617c1760-0dca-409c-af2a-c614f0530e07","text":"comment 23"},{"id":"e325094c-886e-42c9-bd59-fdd7a189b384","pid":"","text":"comment 24"},{"id":"f3b8b0f9-edef-4ee6-9555-42e8595f854c","pid":"e325094c-886e-42c9-bd59-fdd7a189b384","text":"comment 25"},{"id":"6e09a231-a2ee-4aa1-a898-57695e6fe153","pid":"","text":"comment 26"},{"id":"63e629d6-c0f9-4b36-ad96-e0c47cf8bb4e","pid":"6e09a231-a2ee-4aa1-a898-57695e6fe153","text":"comment 27"},{"id":"d7b698f1-8757-46db-a6e6-5141a481b42b","pid":"","text":"comment 28"},{"id":"a7e3d522-553c-44f1-befa-047bd94f0e59","pid":"","text":"comment 29"},{"id":"fe78ce24-c2c8-4d00-b96d-8b8be9ce0f06","pid":"","text":"comment 30"},{"id":"fabdccb5-a024-4476-bd51-7d55fb685c42","pid":"","text":"comment 31"},{"id":"608d0693-6e43-46a0-9e54-107da6adb109","pid":"fabdccb5-a024-4476-bd51-7d55fb685c42","text":"comment 32"}]`

const queue = JSON.parse(datajson)

const result = []

const queueMap = new Map(queue.map(item => [item.id, item]))

for (const item of queue) {
  if (item.pid !== '') {
    const parent = queueMap.get(item.pid)
    if (parent) {
      if (!parent.children) {
        parent.children = []
      }
      parent.children.push(item)
    }
  }
}

for (const [_, value] of queueMap) {
  if (value.pid === '') {
    result.push(value)
  }
}

function recursiveCount(res) {
  let count = res.length
  res.forEach(item => {
    if (item.children) {
      count += recursiveCount(item.children)
    }
  });
  return count
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
console.log("comments", queue.length, "arranged", recursiveCount(result))
```

---

Runable Go Example: https://gist.github.com/dlford/9e66069cfc7fb9afc649c5e3dc650083

Runable JS Example: https://gist.github.com/dlford/f6f4a383a99f65659895ed51d1a4b651

Go code output (see counts at bottom): https://gist.github.com/dlford/302c4db939c21d15132848368caa01ec

JS code output (see counts at bottom): https://gist.github.com/dlford/60ab49d0466c957c7745059022e27e09

Comment: Your algorithm looks too complicated. You can do this simply in three steps: 1) Put every nested comment in a map, keyed with id, 2) for every nested comment in the map, add it to its parent's child list, and 3) collect all nested comments with parent=""

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that got me close, but still not working correctly yet (please see my update to the question)

Comment: The point of putting things in a map is to remove the lookup code. Simply use: `parent=queue[comment.Parent]; if parent!=nil { parent.Children=append(parent.Children, comment) ;}`

Comment: That gives the same results

Comment: Are you sure all parent IDs are valid and exist? In any case, it is hard to tell what's wrong with it without some real data showing the input and the output.

Comment: I am positive all the parent IDs are valid, you can do a quick recursive count on the output and print that out compared to the input to test. I can add more detail when I get home tonight if needed. I can probably manually nest them for comparison

Comment: Ok, I added the recursive count to the go example up top, as well as a javascript implementation that works correctly for comparison. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `Children` in `NestedComment` needed to also be stored as a pointer.

Working example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// Comment from Database
type Comment struct {
    ID       string `json:"id"`
    ParentID string `json:"pid"`
    Text     string `json:"text"`
}

// NestedComment output
type NestedComment struct {
    Comment
    Children []*NestedComment `json:"children,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    // Some comment data from DB
    jsondata := `[{"id":"f1c3a838-f4b4-4ebd-bb1b-d3e4c0dce27d","pid":"6a162b3f-9341-46e9-95f7-dedc6cd06868","text":"comment 1"},{"id":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","pid":"","text":"comment 2"},{"id":"4c93a789-ecab-4173-954c-b039cd3a9e17","pid":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","text":"comment 3"},{"id":"c7974b6d-67e1-47d0-84fa-c78d51682df2","pid":"131cf4bb-1971-43a2-992f-2cbb042a4184","text":"comment 4"},{"id":"386c4439-4596-47c1-99bf-cb479055fe5a","pid":"","text":"comment 5"},{"id":"5ef0816e-ea13-4a7e-8009-e67ee08ef906","pid":"386c4439-4596-47c1-99bf-cb479055fe5a","text":"comment 6"},{"id":"96b0a536-602b-4f3f-a352-020f22cdfb18","pid":"","text":"comment 7"},{"id":"d0f11e98-deea-4fd5-becb-8f406ebcae83","pid":"96b0a536-602b-4f3f-a352-020f22cdfb18","text":"comment 8"},{"id":"bad87461-3cbf-4ecb-a8c7-36876b57d652","pid":"","text":"comment 9"},{"id":"e3ee6f90-495f-4348-9c29-bd6e15ec3b39","pid":"bad87461-3cbf-4ecb-a8c7-36876b57d652","text":"comment 10"},{"id":"6a162b3f-9341-46e9-95f7-dedc6cd06868","pid":"","text":"comment 11"},{"id":"041c7c2d-0688-491e-b6cd-899eac95bd3d","pid":"","text":"comment 12"},{"id":"5acdf3ff-345b-47a5-bd66-a6687a1441b7","pid":"041c7c2d-0688-491e-b6cd-899eac95bd3d","text":"comment 13"},{"id":"aaee2ae5-7e3a-4435-a094-83bf6b77abfb","pid":"","text":"comment 14"},{"id":"6108b28c-a7af-4c5a-a38c-c22db0d34b31","pid":"aaee2ae5-7e3a-4435-a094-83bf6b77abfb","text":"comment 15"},{"id":"1736393e-95b0-4f5d-a149-50fe52c28350","pid":"","text":"comment 16"},{"id":"b646f202-17aa-4af9-b8dc-c1d8ff3529ac","pid":"1736393e-95b0-4f5d-a149-50fe52c28350","text":"comment 17"},{"id":"a8827b1d-fdbc-41c2-bdb5-38e8b308dedc","pid":"b646f202-17aa-4af9-b8dc-c1d8ff3529ac","text":"comment 18"},{"id":"76e49597-6039-4cb5-a595-556ccc2e3c12","pid":"a8827b1d-fdbc-41c2-bdb5-38e8b308dedc","text":"comment 19"},{"id":"07dc4b90-65d3-4f75-8351-457305988235","pid":"76e49597-6039-4cb5-a595-556ccc2e3c12","text":"comment 20"},{"id":"2d4e838b-82df-4ca0-bf9b-f1dfb99d6763","pid":"07dc4b90-65d3-4f75-8351-457305988235","text":"comment 21"},{"id":"617c1760-0dca-409c-af2a-c614f0530e07","pid":"","text":"comment 22"},{"id":"712c0b7e-a9e4-40fd-ab78-c39b483b1435","pid":"617c1760-0dca-409c-af2a-c614f0530e07","text":"comment 23"},{"id":"e325094c-886e-42c9-bd59-fdd7a189b384","pid":"","text":"comment 24"},{"id":"f3b8b0f9-edef-4ee6-9555-42e8595f854c","pid":"e325094c-886e-42c9-bd59-fdd7a189b384","text":"comment 25"},{"id":"6e09a231-a2ee-4aa1-a898-57695e6fe153","pid":"","text":"comment 26"},{"id":"63e629d6-c0f9-4b36-ad96-e0c47cf8bb4e","pid":"6e09a231-a2ee-4aa1-a898-57695e6fe153","text":"comment 27"},{"id":"d7b698f1-8757-46db-a6e6-5141a481b42b","pid":"","text":"comment 28"},{"id":"a7e3d522-553c-44f1-befa-047bd94f0e59","pid":"","text":"comment 29"},{"id":"fe78ce24-c2c8-4d00-b96d-8b8be9ce0f06","pid":"","text":"comment 30"},{"id":"fabdccb5-a024-4476-bd51-7d55fb685c42","pid":"","text":"comment 31"},{"id":"608d0693-6e43-46a0-9e54-107da6adb109","pid":"fabdccb5-a024-4476-bd51-7d55fb685c42","text":"comment 32"}]`

    var comments []Comment

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsondata), &comments)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    arranged := ArrangeComments(comments)

    arrangedjson, _ := json.MarshalIndent(arranged, "", "  ")

    fmt.Println(string(arrangedjson))
    fmt.Println("comments", len(comments), "arranged", recursiveCount(arranged))
}

func recursiveCount(arranged []*NestedComment) int {
    count := len(arranged)
    for _, item := range arranged {
        count += recursiveCount(item.Children)
    }
    return count
}

// Nesting function -------------------------------------------------------------------------

func ArrangeComments(comments []Comment) []*NestedComment {
    // Map to hold references to NestedComment by their ID
    queue := make(map[string]*NestedComment)

    // Result slice
    var result []*NestedComment

    // First, create all NestedComments and store references in the map
    for _, comment := range comments {
        nc := &NestedComment{Comment: comment}
        queue[comment.ID] = nc
    }

    // Second, loop through the map and add children to their parents
    for _, comment := range queue {
        if comment.ParentID != "" {
            parent := queue[comment.Comment.ParentID]
            if parent != nil {
                parent.Children = append(parent.Children, comment)
            }
        }
    }

    // Third, loop through the map and add all root comments to the result slice
    for _, comment := range queue {
        if comment.ParentID == "" {
            result = append(result, comment)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```